# A good book dedicated to study integration on chains and manifolds

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have read m. Spivak's calculus on manifolds(the first three chapters)
and I believe that I understood it well, however I had problems with the chapters concerning integration on chains and manifolds(perhaps because I'm a selflearner with no instructor) it just got very dull and with no enough exposure.....
So I'm asking if you could help me with finding a book (hopefully available in pdf) to resume my study for the topics I've had problems with(integration on chains and manifolds) ...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two main competing texts in the same age are Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* and Loomis and Sternberg's [*Advanced Calculus*](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf). I'm now reading chapter 8 of Loomis & Sternberg and haven't read chapters 9-11 (the chapters about calculus on manifolds) yet, and so I can't comment on its exposition on calculus on manifolds, but the book has a free legal electronic copy and you may see if you like it or not.

Comment: I don't believe that Spivak's approach is the best approach for the first time dealing with differential forms and Stokes's Theorem. You might want to try some of my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile.

Comment: Thanks for the comments